# How to open new tab

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

```
Robot rb =new Robot();

rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);

rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Comment: What is issue with your trial code ?

Comment: Please mention question correctly

Comment: XPath is defined as XML path. It is a syntax or language for finding any element on the web page using XML path expression.

Comment: XPath is defined as XML path. It is a syntax or language for finding any element on the web page using XML path expression.

Comment: XPath is defined as XML path. It is a syntax or language for finding any element on the web page using XML path expression.

Comment: XPath is defined as XML path. It is a syntax or language for finding any element on the web page using XML path expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a pause after creating new tab as follows:

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
// add a pause
Thread.sleep(1000);
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); 
// open website in a new tab
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

or even better use `WebDriverWait`:

```
Robot rb =new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

this will wait at least 10 seconds until number of tabs will be 2.

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this,

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this you can open new tab by using `JavascriptExecutor` or `Keys.chord`

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

or use

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open();");
```